# Update declared variables in GIthub Actions workflow

Tags: shell, yaml, github-actions

How does one go about updating a variable that is declared in github action workflow?

Consider the following:

```
name: Test Variable

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
env:
  DAY_OF_WEEK: Monday

jobs:
  job1:
    name: Job1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      Greeting: Hello
    steps:
      - name: "Say Hello John it's Monday"
        run: |
          echo $Greeting=Holla
          echo "$Greeting $First_Name. Today is $DAY_OF_WEEK!"
        env:
          First_Name: John
      
      - name: "Eval"
        run: echo $Greeting $First_Name
```

So here I'm attempting to update `Greeting` then eval it later but GH is throwing

`Invalid workflow file.You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 21.`

So, if I were to update `Greeting` `First_Name` and `DAY_OF_WEEK`how would I go about doing that?

### Update

Fixed yaml syntax but the variable is not updated. Output for Eval is

```
Run echo $Greeting $First_Name
  echo $Greeting $First_Name
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    DAY_OF_WEEK: Monday
    Greeting: Hello
Hello
```

Comment: Indention is part of yaml syntax. The `on` block should not be indented out like that

Comment: Thats just SO text entry. Thats not the issue here. I'll try and update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a variable:

```
run echo "Greeting=HOLLA" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

using the variable

```
run echo "$Greeting"
```

docs:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable

(Also make sure yours yml-file's indentation is correct.)